# Emscripten clang hello_world.cpp link error

Tags: clang, emscripten

I am trying to follow the tutorial on [Emscripten setup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Emscripten/Introducing/Emscripten_beginners_tutorial).I have installed the SDK and now trying to test clang compilation.

Trying simple : clang tests/hello_world.cpp  I am getting the following error:

> c:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.13.0>clang++
>   tests/hello_world.cpp  hello_world-005255.o : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol printf referenc ed in function main LINK :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mainCRTStartup hell.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals clang++.exe: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see inv ocation)

I am executing the command in VS 2010 cmd and my system is 64bit (Emscripten version is 64bit too)

Comment: Did you run it with "-v" as suggested in the error message? What is the output? You can capture it into a file called "log" by doing "clang -v tests/hello_world.cpp >log 2>&1".

Comment: Finally got an answer from the dev team there.Clang doesn't work good on Windows.

Comment: But this seems to be a simple and solvable link problem, perhaps a library not in linker paths. For the record, following the tutorial, I am able to compile hello_world_sdl.cpp by emcc into html, but not hello_world.cpp by clang - a similar yet different linker path issue.